# How to extend object with multiple functions in one call?

Tags: object, rebol, rebol3

In Rebol 3 you can dynamically add keys and values to objects with append:

```
>> foo: object [x: 10]

>> append foo [y: 20 z: 30]
== make object! [
    x: 10
    y: 20
    z: 30
]
```

But if you try that with functions, it doesn't seem to work:

```
>> foo: object [x: 10]

>> append foo reduce [y: does [print "y"] z: does [print "z"]]
** Script error: invalid argument: make function! [[][print "y"]]
** Where: append
** Near: append foo reduce [y: does [print "y"] z: does [print "z"]]
```

You can add a function with extend:

```
>> foo: object [x: 10]

>> extend foo 'y does [print "y"]

>> foo/y
y
```

But that only lets you add one at a time.  How can you add a block of arbitrary keys/values to an object, with some of them functions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As extend is just a mezzanine,

```
>> source extend
extend: make function! [[
   {Extend an object, map, or block type with word and value pair.}
   obj [object! map! block! paren!] "object to extend (modified)"
   word [any-word!]
   val
][
  if :val [append obj reduce [to-set-word word :val]]
  :val
]]
```

you can with ease define your own extend or a new function

```
extends: make function! [  [{Extend an object}
   obj  [object!]
   funcblk [block!]  "with pair(s) of functionname and function"
] [
   foreach [name funcon] funcblk [append obj reduce [to-set-word name get funcon]]
]]
```

and then you are able to do

```
>> r: does [print "y"] s: does [print "z"]
>> extends foo [y r z s]
== make object! [
   x: 10
   y: make function! [[][print "y"]]
   z: make function! [[][print "z"]]
]
```

or for short

```
>> append foo reduce [quote y: does [print "y"] quote z: does [print "z"]]
== make object! [
    x: 10
    y: make function! [[][print "y"]]
    z: make function! [[][print "z"]]
]
```

Comment: Argh, obvious!  It was trying to do the assignment.  :-/  I should pay more attention.  Thanks.